# Multiple Email Addresses Using Mail::to()

Tags: laravel

Will this work?

```
$email_address = 'john@domain.com, doe@domain.com';

Mail::to($email_address)->send(new EmailTemplate($emailObject));
```

I've been googling around but I cannot find a definite answer.

Comment: Have you tried it? Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Rwd - laravel 5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work better with an array:

```
$email_address = ['john@domain.com', 'doe@domain.com'];

Mail::to($email_address)->send(new EmailTemplate($emailObject));
```

Comment: it does worked if it's an array, accepted and upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

```
$email_address = ['john@domain.com','doe@domain.com'];

foreach($email_address as $email)
{
    Mail::to($email)->send(new EmailTemplate($emailObject));
}
```

Comment: it would work but doesn't need to loop if it's an array, upvoted anyway, thank you.